# Confusion about the code

Tags: plotting

1.First, I defined the spherical harmonic function and converted it to Cartesian coordinates.

```mathematica
Clear["Global`*"];
(*定义球谐函数*)
Ylm = SphericalHarmonicY[1, 0, #1, #2] &;

(*球坐标系到直角坐标系的转换*)
球坐标系 = {r, theta, phi};
坐标转换 = CoordinateTransformData["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", 
   "Mapping", {x, y, z}];
rule = Thread[球坐标系 -> 坐标转换];

(*将球谐函数转换为直角坐标系下的表示*)
Ylm[theta, phi];
pZ = Ylm[theta, phi] /. rule
```

2.Then, I defined g[x,y,z] to define the wave function.

```mathematica
g[x_, y_, z_] := If[x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 0, None, Evaluate@pZ]
```

3.Finally, I plotted the image.

```mathematica
atomplot1 = ContourPlot3D[
   g[x, y, z]^2,
   {x, -15, 15},
   {y, -15, 15},
   {z, -15, 15},
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z},
     Hue[g[x, y, z]]]];


atomplot2 = SliceContourPlot3D[
  Evaluate[g[x, y, z + 15]^2],
  z == -15,
  {x, -15, 15},
  {y, -15, 15},
  {z, -15, 15},
  PlotRange -> All,
  Axes -> False,
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]

Show[atomplot1, atomplot2,
 PlotRange -> All,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .6},
 ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1},
 FaceGrids -> {Back, Left}]
```

[image]

I have some questions about this process

1. For the code `g[x_, y_, z_] := If[x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 0, None, Evaluate@pZ]`, I have to use Evaluate to make atomplot1 plot work.
2. I have used `If[x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 0, None, Evaluate@pZ]` to avoid the situation of 0/0, but in fact, this error still occurs when plotting the final image,like this
   [image]

For the above two questions I don't know why

Comment: Since you can read Chinese, check this: http://note.youdao.com/noteshare?id=a9c14381c11b44ad47980c44c200d529

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function localizes its variables. Here is a small example to show this:

```
Clear[f, t, x]
t := x^2;
f[x_] := t;
f[3]

x^2
```

The output is not 9 but x^2 because the localized "x" is not the same as the global x.

Further "None" is not a numerical value. Replace it by zero.

Now, to make your code working properly, we define functions with proper arguments:

```
Clear[pz,g]
pZ[x_, y_, z_] = Ylm[theta, phi] /. rule;
g[x_, y_, z_] = If[x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 0, 0, pZ[x, y, z]];
```

Now your code should work without "Evaluate" and 1/0:

```
atomplot1 = 
 ContourPlot3D[g[x, y, z]^2, {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, {z, -15, 15},
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[g[x, y, z]]]];
atomplot2 = 
  SliceContourPlot3D[g[x, y, z + 15]^2, 
   z == -15, {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, {z, -15, 15}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
Show[atomplot1, atomplot2, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .6}, 
 ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, FaceGrids -> {Back, Left}]
```

[image]